# What does "drive-in teller" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *drive-in teller* mean in the following sentence?

> It's as those pneumatic canisters you see when you go to a drive-in
>   teller at a bank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes they are called drive-throughs, or even drive-ups, at least in the U.S.

Essentially, it's a way to visit the bank without getting out of your car.  Some drive-throughs only have an ATM, others let you interact with a bank teller.

The left half of the picture below shows a bank's ATM drive-thru.  On the right, a teller is putting said canister in the chute, which will then be transported to the customer in his car. Notice the microphone used to communicate between the teller in the bank and the customer in his car.

[image]

Comment: So, drive-in teller is the person (girl on the picture) that do some operations with the canisters?

Comment: Please, download the pictures to the answer. They are nice and can disappear when the URLs are dead.

Comment: Most interesting. I've not seen that before.

Comment: The entire drive-thru area can be collectively knows as the "drive-thru teller."  The person in the picture might be the "teller at the drive-thru window."  On slow days, I've seen one teller alternate between customers at the drive-through, and customers in the lobby.

Comment: That girl's hot.. jus sayin